# Extension functions issue

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

Run into some difficulties while using extension functions with existing java api. Here some pseudocode

```
public class Test {

public Test call() {
    return this;
}

public Test call(Object param) {
    return this;
}

public void configure1() {
}

public void configure2(boolean value) {
}
}
```

Kotlin test

```
fun Test.call(toApply: Test.() -> Unit): Test {
return call()
    .apply(toApply)
}
fun Test.call(param: Any, toApply: Test.() -> Unit): Test {
return call(param)
    .apply(toApply)
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val test = Test()
//refers to java method; Unresolved reference: configure1;Unresolved reference: configure2
test.call {
    configure1()
    configure2(true)
}
//refers to my extension function and works fine
test.call(test) {
    configure1()
    configure2(true)
}
}
```

Why only function with param works fine ? what’s the difference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin will always give precedence to the classes member functions. Since `Test:call(Object)` is a possible match, Kotlin selects that method rather than your extension function.

The extension function with the added parameter is resolved the way you expect because the `Test` class does not have any member functions that would take precedent (no matching signature), so your extension method is selected.

Here is a link to the Kotlin documentation as to how extension functions are resolved: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically

Comment: Ok, so i changed "Object param" to "Test param" in java and "param: Any" to "param: Test" in Kotlin and it start refers test.call{} to my extension function. But Test:call(Test) is possible match too. Why behaviour changed?

Comment: Your extension function takes a lambda of type `Test.() -> Unit`, so `Test:call(Test)` is NOT also a possible match.